# Is it possible to have two or more active modal windows at the same time?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on feedback form in my application. It also has some windows, which must be modal. The problem is that user cannot open feedback form, while one of that modal windows is opened. So is there any way to make feedback form modal and possible to be opened and used along other modal window?

Comment: If you have more than one, they are not modal windows.

Comment: I mean, that there are some functions: filter, sorting, etc... And each of them is presented by modal window. And I want to have an ability to open one more modal window along other. @Aron

Comment: It's not a modal dialog if there are two of them. A modal dialog takes control and focus away from all other dialogs. Therefore THERE CAN ONLY BE ONE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided that you only have one active at a time:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += (s1, e1) =>
        {
            var window1 = new Window();
            window1.Owner = this;
            window1.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "This is modal window 1" };

            window1.Loaded += (s2, e2) =>
            {
                var window2 = new Window();
                window2.Owner = window1;
                window2.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "This is modal window 2" };
                window2.ShowDialog();
            };

            window1.ShowDialog();
        };
    }
}
```

This particular code is a bit messy, it's just to demonstrate that it can be done. If you want a more robust example then check out [my article on implementing dialog boxes in MVVM](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM).

It's also possible to set the `window2.Owner` to `this` and get two active modal dialogs at the same time, but it means you have to rely on alt-tab or programmatic control to switch between them. This is almost certainly not the behavior you want, but again it is possible for the extremely rare cases where you'd want to do such a thing.